# WPF: Printing a multi-page TextBlock

Tags: wpf, printing

I'm using a FlowDocument to print in WPF using the method described [here](http://roecode.wordpress.com/2007/12/21/using-flowdocument-xaml-to-print-xps-documents/) but I'm running into problems trying to span multiple pages. Just under the root of the FlowDocument, I have a textblock, eg:

```
<Paragraph>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Directions}" />
</Paragraph>
```

If the text it's bound to is longer than one page, only one page is displayed and the rest is just truncated. Is there any way I can span multiple pages with a TextBlock?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, you can't. Must be a bindable Run class. Search Google for examples.

Comment: I've read about BindableRuns, but I was hoping to avoid them. Thanks for your reply.